# C++ map inversion initialize

Tags: c++, c++11

When I was reading some article I saw something strange (for me).

When I'm using a map I use it like this:

```
std::map<std::string, MyClass> Map;
//and add elements:
Map['someting'] = myObject;
```

And this is fine and intelligible. But in this article I saw this:

```
MyClass& object = Map['something_new'];
//and then, initialize the object
object.method();
//and later I can use this map
Map['something_new'];
```

And... it works. But I don't understand how. I initialize an object reference, not map, but this works like I just added an element to my map. Could someone explain this to me?

Answer (score 3):

As [documentation for `std::map`'s `operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at) says:

> **Returns a reference** to the value that is mapped to a key equivalent to key, **performing an insertion** if such key does not already exist.

In other words, the design of `std::map` is such that you *always* get a reference to an existing valid element via `operator[]`, be it one that existed before the call or one that was created on the fly.

Other designs could have been possible, of course. For example, an exception could have been thrown if the key does not exist, or the behaviour could have been made undefined. But the automatic element creation is what `std::map` has ended up with.

If you don't want elements to be inserted automatically, then you should not use `operator[]`. You can use the following instead:

```
auto const find_iter = Map.find("something_new");
if (find_iter != Map.end())
{
    MyClass& object = *find_iter;
    // ...
}
else
{
    // do whatever you want when there is no "something_new" element
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `std::map` automatically creates a new object using the default constructor if you access a not existing key.

See this example:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

class Demo {
public:
    Demo() { std::cout << "ctor" << std::endl; }
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    std::map<std::string, Demo> m;
    std::cout << "Access unknown element." << std::endl;
    m["a"];
    m["b"];
    m["c"];
}
```

The output is:

```
Access unknown element.
ctor
ctor
ctor
```

Each not existing element accessed is automatically constructed using the default constructor. This is also working with simple data types like `int`.

Answer (score 1):

`operator[]` (element_access) is not a const function; it actually inserts a new element in the map if a value for the key does not already exist.

`map['non_existing_key']` will actually increase the `size()` of the container:

> If `k` does not match the key of any element in the container, the
>   function inserts a new element with that key and returns a reference
>   to its mapped value. Notice that this always increases the container
>   size by one, even if no mapped value is assigned to the element (the
>   element is constructed using its default constructor).

Comment: Please cite your sources with a link.

Answer (score 0):

#### The First Code

```
std::map<std::string, MyClass> Map;
//and add elements:
Map["someting"] = myObject;
```

1. You create the map `Map`.
2. You call the subscript operator [`operator[]`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/operator%5B%5D/) of `Map`. Assuming that the key `"something"` doesn't exists, it create a `MyClass` instance corresponding to this key by calling the default constructor of `MyClass`.
3. The subscript operator returns a non-constant reference to this newly created instance.
4. The assignment operator either calls the implicit or explicit, copy or move assignment operator of the `MyClass` instance inside `Map`, sends `myObject` as an argument to it.
5. Assuming that the assignment operation has gone well, myObject is assigned to the key.

#### The Second Code

```
MyClass& object = Map["something_new"];
//and then, initialize the object
object.method();
//and later I can use this map
Map["something_new"];
```

1. You create a new `MyClass` (assuming that it doesn't exist) instance corresponding the key `"something_new"` by calling the default constructor of `MyClass`.
2. You get a reference to that instance.
3. You do your job (i.e.; call `method()`) by using that reference.
4. Later, you can get the same reference by using the same key.

#### Result

There is nothing to compare here. The first code makes an assignment, and the second one calls a method.